# Magento 1.9 - Zend/Currency - Wrong format... missing 0

Tags: magento, zend-framework

We are getting this error over night. Any ideas why this is happening?

Could it be a server miss configuration on currency format?

Here's the report log from Magento:

````
a:5:{i:0;s:25:"Wrong format... missing 0";i:1;s:4671:"#0 /home/magento_web/public_html/lib/Zend/Currency.php(194): Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber(0, Array)
#1 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(270): Zend_Currency->toCurrency(0, Array)
#2 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(242): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(0, Array)
#3 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(222): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision(0, 2, Array, true, false)
#4 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(1008): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format(0, Array, true)
#5 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php(61): Mage_Core_Model_Store->formatPrice(0)
#6 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/design/frontend/et_edge/default/template/et/ajax/cart/inside.phtml(20): Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data->formatPrice(0)
#7 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/design/frontend/et_edge/default/template/et/ajax/cart.phtml(18): include('/home/magento_web/p...')
#8 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/magento_web/p...')
#9 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/et_edg...')
#10 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('ajaxCart', true)
#14 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/design/frontend/et_edge/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(75): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('ajaxCart')
#15 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/magento_web/p...')
#16 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/et_edg...')
#17 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#21 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/design/frontend/et_edge/default/template/page/1column.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#22 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/magento_web/p...')
#23 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/et_edg...')
#24 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '5')
#30 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '5')
#31 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#32 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#33 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /home/magento_web/public_html/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /home/magento_web/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:15:"/enable-cookies";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"pt";}```

Thank you so much!
````

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312025/unknown-date-format-neither-date-nor-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-found-magent

As a temporary fix all iconv_strpos with strpos in \lib\Zend\Locale\Format.php except on line 1113 to avoid issues with 4 parameters sent to strpos